# How to recursively compress subdirectory's files with password

Tags: linux, bash, compression, zip

I need to recursively compress subdirectory's files with password and then delete the uncompressed file in bash file.

There are zip files and other files. I don't want to compress zip files again.  I only want to compress uncompressed files and keep the file name as the compressed file name.

For instance, if the file name is `aaa10.dat` then the zip file name must `aaa10.zip` and compress it with password.

After compressing, I want to delete the uncompressed file.

[directory structure]

```
dir1/aaa1.dat ... aaa10.dat
dir1/dir2/dir2_subdir1/aaa.zip, aaa.dat
dir1/dir3/dir3_subdir1/aaa1.dat ... aaa10.dat
dir1/dir3/dir3_subdir2/aaa1.dat ... aaa20.dat, aaa1.zip ... aaa10.zip
dir1/dir3/dir3_subdir2/dir3_subdir2_subdir1/aaa1.dat ... aaa20.dat, aaa1.zip ... aaa10.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a fairly complicated `find` command, which finds all of the ".dat" files and then zips them up.  But putting the zip part into separate script is much easier to show:

```
find . -name '*.dat' -exec my-script {} \;
```

and `my-script` (which has to be in your `PATH`):

```
#!/bin/sh
zip -P my-password -m $(dirname $1)/$(basename $1 .dat).zip $1
```

and *`my-password`* is of course whatever you chose.